# Have Clipper Merge Polygon's (with hole) into One instead of Two Polygons

Tags: c#, polygon, polygons, clipperlib

I am merging a number of polygon's using the clipper library and am having one main issue. When a polygon exists with a hole in it, I would like one single closed path to represent the polygon including the hole. What the tool is giving me is two closed paths (one for the outer and inner outline of the polygon, the inner outline also being the outline of the hole).

To better illustrate, the image linked below was taken from another stack overflow question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699298/clipper-does-not-create-hole-when-making-a-union%22here%22)) and is essentially the opposite of my question. The orange polygon with the red 'X' is what I want - as it contains only one closed path. It seems the clipper library has been updated since and now this type of union results in two paths (orange polygon to the right of the one crossed out).

[image: See the Polygon Image Here]

Is there a way to choose the previous method that I am missing?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue somehow? I have exactly the same problem.